# Google Fit Data Update Notifications

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to integrate Google Fit SDK. Is there any way to get data update notifications from Google Fit for Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add an `OnDataPointListener` to any `DataSource` or `DataType` to receive updates when data is added to the respective type in real time. You do this through the [Sensors API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors).